# React native hardware back button is not working after login and logout functions?

Tags: react-native

React native hardware back button is not working after login and logout functions, I am changing the stack navigator but it not working. But once you close the app and open, then hardware back button it works normally.The problem when I am changing the stack navigator it is not working.Any solution?
React Navigation version 5.9.8

Comment: Please share your code. Thank you.

Comment: You must have added the BackHandler in a screen which is not mounted yet.
Just move that logic to the initial screen or App.js.